# Analysis is switched off in re-sharper

Tags: c#, resharper

I am getting an error says `Analysis is switched off` in one of the file in solution. I am not sure why re-sharper is not considering this file alone.

Please let me know, in case somebody have solution for the same. How to switch on analysis in re-sharper for one file alone?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons for analysis being switched off in ReSharper. One is that the file is source, added by a NuGet package. This isn't your code, so won't necessarily be to your standards, so it's not fair to flag issues such as naming standard violations in this codebase. Another reason is that the file is a generated file, or contains generated regions (such as Windows Forms designer files). You can configure this in ReSharper → Options → Generated Code. Finally, there is another settings page: ReSharper → Options → Third-party Code, which allows disabling just analysis, or analysis AND indexing in certain code.